# Button that assigns different color to text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I have a problem but I don't know what it could be. Iam supposed to link my javascript to my html. There are three buttons that should turn the text to a diffrent color on clicking. But it is not working.

```js
// this is the red button
const header = document.querySelector("#header");
const clicker = document.querySelector(".clicker-red");

clicker.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  header.classList.add("large");
});

// this is the green button

const clicker = document.querySelector(".clicker-green");

clicker.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  header.classList.add("large");
});

// this is the purple button

const clicker = document.querySelector(".clicker-pruple");

clicker.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  header.classList.add("large");
});
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: You have declared variable `clicker` three times with `const` keyword, you need to change the variable names

Comment: 3 variables of const type are declared  with same name which will produce error..Change the names.

Comment: thanks. yeah that was the problem

Answer (score 5):

As I have said in the comments, You cannot declare variable with same name in the same Lexical Environment (i.e, in the same block).

So, you need to change the variable name.

Here is the working example.

```js
const header = document.querySelector("#header");
const clickerRed = document.querySelector(".clicker-red");

clickerRed.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});

// //this is the green button

const clickerGreen = document.querySelector(".clicker-green");

clickerGreen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});

// // this is the purple button

const clickerPurple = document.querySelector(".clicker-purple");

clickerPurple.addEventListener("click", () => {
  header.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
});
```

```html
<div id="header">
Header</div>
<button class="clicker-red" type="button">Red</button>
<button class="clicker-green" type="button">Green</button>
<button class="clicker-purple" type="button">Purple</button>
```